# selecionar uma das palavras contidas na lista

Tags: python

Digitar um palavras numa lista e depois procurar pela palavra digitada

```
lista = []
i = 0
palavra = ''
while (palavra.lower() != 'sair'):
    i += 1
    palavra = str(input('digite alguma palavra: '))
    lista.append(palavra)
ultima_palavra = len(lista) - 1
lista.remove(lista[ultima_palavra])
print(lista)
```

Comment: qual a função em python que procura strings numa lista?
não pode ser uma palavra específica, pois o programa permite que se digite qualquer palavra para depois procurar entre o que foi digitado.

Comment: Mas o que você está a tentar fazer ? Explique por palavras como você idealiza a interação do usuario com o programa e respetivo funcionamento, pois o código que tem não joga com o titulo da pergunta.

Comment: por exemplo eu digito: azul, dia, noite
depois eu digito "sair"
então aparece a opção para o usuário digitar uma palavra, se ela constar na lista aparecerá uma frase dizendo para ele que há tal palavra na lista, se não ele receberá uma informação de que a palavra não está na lista (no exemplo citado "vermelho" não estaria na lista e azul sim)

Comment: lista = []
i = 0
palavra = ''
buscada = ''
while (palavra.lower() != 'sair'):
    i += 1
    palavra = str(input('digite alguma palavra: '))
    lista.append(palavra)
ultima_palavra = len(lista) - 1
lista.remove(lista[ultima_palavra])
print(lista)
buscada = str(input('digite a palavra procurada: '))
if buscada in lista:
    print('a palavra', buscada, 'buscada foi encontrada na lista')
else:
    print('palavra não encontrada.')

Comment: obg pelo interesse em ajudar.

Comment: Então mas porque o `append` e `remove` se apenas quer verificar se o elemento existe na lista ? Para tal o ideal é utilizar o operador `in` como ja foi mostrado na resposta que tem no momento. Algo tão simples como `if palavra in lista:`

Comment: porque se não aparece a palavra "sair" no fim da ista.
e como ela é necessária para o programa parar o laço, usei a opção de removê-la.

Comment: o append é para que as palavras digitadas durante a execução do programa sejam postas na lista.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está com uma variável inútil i.

```
for palavra in lista:
    if palavra == buscada:
        print('a palavra buscada foi encontrada na lista')
```

Outra forma seria:

```
if buscada in lista:
    print('palavra encontrada')
```

Acredito que você poderia ter encontrado a resposta para sua pergunta em algum outro tópico.

Comment: Obrigado por responder Ken.
Mas onde se encaixaria o "for"? dentro do laço while ou fora?

Comment: Obrigado por me ajudar a encontrar a resposta

Comment: lista = []
i = 0
palavra = ''
buscada = ''
while (palavra.lower() != 'sair'):
    i += 1
    palavra = str(input('digite alguma palavra: '))
    lista.append(palavra)
ultima_palavra = len(lista) - 1
lista.remove(lista[ultima_palavra])
print(lista)
buscada = str(input('digite a palavra procurada: '))
if buscada in lista:
    print('a palavra', buscada, 'buscada foi encontrada na lista')
else:
    print('palavra não encontrada.')

Comment: Boa! As duas formas são válidas. Vale lembrar que na maioria dos casos a segunda forma será mais performática, por que o `for` vai percorrer a lista inteira mesmo depois de achar a palavra. Já com o `in`, ele vai parar a iteração assim que achar o elemento buscado.